# Как выбрать ФИО из списка строк и изменить формат даты?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, datetime, форматирование

Нужно написать функцию, которая принимает список строк и возвращает список словарей в формате `{"name": name, "date": date}`, где:

- name - имя автора
- date - дата в формате `dd/mm/yyyy`

Например:  `[{"name": Wilkie Collins, "date": 08/01/1824}, {"name": James Joyce, "date": 13/01/1941}...]`

Список строк:

```
 8th January 1824 - Wilkie Collins's birthday, author of Woman in White
 13th January 1941 - James Joyce's birthday, author of Ulysses
 14th January 1898 - Lewis Carroll's birthday, author of Alice in Wonderland
 3rd January 1892 - J. R. R. Tolkien's birthday, author of The Hobbit & The Lord of the Rings
 18th January 1936 - Rudyard Kipling's death, author of Jungle Book
 19th January 1809 - Edgar Allan Poe's birthday, author of The Tell Tale Heart
```

Я начал писать код:

```
def dict_names():
    dict_names = re.findall(r"[A-Z]+[a-z]+['s]", list_name)
    return dict_names
```

В итоге выбирает только фамилии, а имя или инициалы не возвращает. Как это исправить? И как отдельно выбрать дату?

Comment: `[A-Z][a-z]*\s[A-Z][a-z]*\'s` - регулярка на имя + инициалы

Comment: `[0-9]{1,2}((th)|(st)|(nd)|(d))\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s[0-9]{4,4}` - регулярка на отлов даты

Comment: так имя выбирает только полностью, а что делать если инициалы могут выглядеть и вот так: J. R. R. Tolkien's и как убрать это  's в конце?

Comment: `([A-Z][a-z]*\.?)+` - ищет отдельно каждое имя, поэтому придётся их объединять через join

Comment: Только теперь и месяца начали добавляться, например January....

Comment: ничего, что в date могут быть как даты рождения, так и смерти? как вы их потом различите? или это не критично?

Comment: это не критично, мне все даты нужны

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Не могу оставлять комментарии, поэтому так: `[a-zA-Z. ]+'`

Потом нужно будет обрезать первый пробел и `'`

Дата: `^ \S+ \S+ \S+`
Пробел после `^` опционален и нужен, если строчки начинаются с пробела.

Comment: dict_names = (''.join(old_dict_names)).strip()[0:-1] впереди пробел убрал, а вот в конце ( ' )  не получается убрать

Comment: Я не питонист, но попробуй return [i.strip(' \'') for i in dict_names] вместо return dict_names

Answer (score 2):

Я бы для таких дат воспользовался [dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) c последующим преобразованием в нужный вам формат `%d/%m/%Y`, а имена - просто `split` по `'s` , если не важен "тип" даты (рождения/смерти):

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse

result_data = []
for row in rows:
    parts = row.split(" - ")
    date =  parse(parts[0]).date().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    name = parts[1].split("'s")[0]

    result_data.append({
        'date': date,
        'name': name
        
    })
```

Для вашего тесткейса:

```py
rows = [
    "8th January 1824 - Wilkie Collins's birthday, author of Woman in White",
    "13th January 1941 - James Joyce's birthday, author of Ulysses",
    "14th January 1898 - Lewis Carroll's birthday, author of Alice in Wonderland",
    "3rd January 1892 - J. R. R. Tolkien's birthday, author of The Hobbit & The Lord of the Rings",
    "18th January 1936 - Rudyard Kipling's death, author of Jungle Book",
    "19th January 1809 - Edgar Allan Poe's birthday, author of The Tell Tale Heart"
]
```

в `result_data` будет список словарей нужного формата:

```
>>>result_data

[
 {'name': 'Wilkie Collins', 'date': '08/01/1824'}, 
 {'name': 'James Joyce', 'date': '13/01/1941'}, 
 {'name': 'Lewis Carroll', 'date': '14/01/1898'}, 
 {'name': 'J. R. R. Tolkien', 'date': '03/01/1892'}, 
 {'name': 'Rudyard Kipling', 'date': '18/01/1936'}, 
 {'name': 'Edgar Allan Poe', 'date': '19/01/1809'}
]
```